# How to read input line by line, instead of by spacing

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a large number of user inputs line by line instead of by spacing.

code:

```
keyword = (input("\n Please enter the keywords "))
keywords = keyword.split(" ")
```

words:

a

abandon

ability

able

abortion

Comment: how would you know when the user finish inputing words?

Comment: When the user enters the text.

Comment: which text?  because in that case a word is a line, so how many words (lines) should the user input then?

Comment: well i'm inputing 3000words

Comment: ok, so you want to read from the `stdin` then right? areyou piping the input then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function ends by pressing `enter` or moving to a new line, so you have to define how you want to finish instead.

If you're looking for a way to enter 5 words like you did in your example, this should be enough:

```
print("\n Please enter the keywords ")
keywords = [input() for i in range(5)]
```

You can change `range(5)` to `range(3000)` or any other number that you wish.

If you would like in input an infinite amount of words until some special keyword is entered (like "quit") you can do this:

```
print("\n Please enter the keywords ")
keywords = []
while True:
    k = input()
    if k == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        keywords.append(k)
```

Comment: If it's indeed 3000 words that makes some sense, it's starting to be really too large for memory perhaps? If you would give us an idea as to what this is used for, we could understand better ways. Without more context, this is the answer for what you directly asked

Comment: I'm using it along with requests to check available urls

Comment: If you're doing 3000 requests and processing them all together without releasing some memory in the process, your problem is not the inputs, your code needs to be rewritten with memory in mind

Comment: You should accept some answer here and ask a new question about the efficiency of that code

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read from the `sys.stdin`, for example:

```
import sys

it = iter(sys.stdin)
while True:
  print(next(it))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/GiddyExcitedOffices)